# Load different page if params are present

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Hi I was wondering if it was possible to open a different page based on if the params are present or not.

I tried the following 2 possibilities:

```
    { 
      path: 'page1', 
      component: Page1,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard],
      children: [
        {
          path: 'page1/:test',
          component: Page2,
          canActivate: [AuthGuard]
        }
      ]
    },
```

And having them seperate

```
    { 
      path: 'page1', 
      component: Page1,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    {
      path: 'page1/:test',
      component: Page2,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }
```

How can I achieve this effect? Because with both these options my browser opens Page1 even if the param `test` is added. Or should I use a different naming convention? (would rather not)

Comment: if there is a param `test`, you don't want `Page1` to be loaded?

Comment: @Maximus exactly. And on `Page1` I want to redirect to `Page2` if a specific button is pressed with a given parameter

Comment: your second configuration should have worked

Comment: Sadly it doesn't, just opens the Page1, just checked to be sure

Comment: can you setup a plunker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaah I figured it out by making the plunker (thanks @Maximus).

I was navigating to: `:8080/page1?test=something` instead of `:8080/page1/something`

The configuration was indeed correct. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

**Order** is important in when declaring **routes**. Specific ones should be declared at first. replace your code with following.

```
{
      path: 'page1/:test',
      component: Page2,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    },
    { 
      path: 'page1', 
      component: Page1,
      canActivate: [AuthGuard]
    }
```

Comment: the order shouldn't matter here, since router tries to match a route _until all url segments are consumed_, so with the url `page1/some` the first block `path: 'page1'` won't match

Comment: Also opens `Page1`

Comment: @Ivaro18, setup a plunker, because the router configuration you showed should work and without a plunker it's hard to tell where you have a problem